# DRF Create object with nested object parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this two classes in my Django Rest Framework project

```
class Call(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    client = models.ForeignKey('client.Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_client')

class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

Then I have my view that simply extend "CreateApiView" without any additional code and then the serializer:

```
class CallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = ClientSerializer()
```

What I simply need to do is to create a Call object after a POST, sending as parameters my client object. The problem is that if I do so, django returns me this error: `A client with that name already exists.`

So I tried to edit the serializer this way `ClientSerializer(read_only=True)` but this time it creates the Call object with Client set to null.

How can I fix this? I know I can simply remove the nested ClientSerializer and then send the ID instead of the whole Client object, but is there a way to do it with the nested serializer?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to customize the create logic of your serializer, as stated here (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

You should then end up with something like the following (not tested):

```py
class CallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = ClientSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['client_id'] = validated_data.pop('client')['id']
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the validation think I want to create the nested object, but in fact I already have them, so it returns "A client with that name already exists".